# Exception handling on AsyncQueryHandler

Tags: android, exception

When using Android's `AsyncQueryHandler`, is there any easy way to handle exceptions thrown from the asynchronous insert or do I need to write my own version of that class?

Comment: During insertion I generate primary keys using the hi-lo algorithm. If my key generator has exhausted its supply of available keys, it throws an `OutOfKeysException`. I need to catch that exception. Something like `AsyncQueryHandler.onError(Throwable err)` would be ideal (that doesn't exist, but to show you what I'm after).

Comment: @chris are you using a custom content provider ?

Comment: @chris so try to catch any errors in ContentProvider.insert()

Comment: @pskink Thank you for the suggestion, but I really don't want to do that. Running out of keys will require some heavy duty error handling, like making an "emergency run" to the sync server to go beg for more keys (this requires authorization, so the user will potentially need to enter credentials), notifying the user of the failure if the server is unreachable etc. It seems like the content provider isn't the right place to do all that.

Comment: sure you are right, when your insert ode throws an exception then return some "error" Uri and check it in onInsertComplete

Comment: You're right, that would work. I have by now come up with a working solution based on extending `AsyncQueryHandler`. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Poking around the `AsyncQueryHandler` source it became clear that I could extend it to suit my needs without too much pain. Since "AsyncQueryHandler exception handling" doesn't give you much on google or SO I've attached my source below in case anybody else ever finds themselves in the same situation.

Basically what it does is, it extends `AsyncQueryHandler`'s internal worker thread and wraps a call through to that thread's `super.handleMessage` in a try-catch block, then sends any caught exceptions back to the main thread in a message, where it gets passed into the `onError` callback. The default `onError` just re-throws the exception.

```
/**
 * Thin wrapper around @link {@link AsyncQueryHandler} that provides a callback to be invoked 
 * if the asynchronous operation caused an exception.
 */
public class SturdyAsyncQueryHandler extends AsyncQueryHandler {
    public SturdyAsyncQueryHandler(ContentResolver cr) {
        super(cr);
    }

    /**
     * Thin wrapper around {@link AsyncQueryHandler.WorkerHandler} that catches any <code>RuntimeException</code>
     * thrown and passes them back in a reply message. The exception that occurred is
     * in the <code>result</code> field.
     */
    protected class SturdyWorkerHandler extends AsyncQueryHandler.WorkerHandler {
        public SturdyWorkerHandler(Looper looper) {
            super(looper);
        }
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            try {
                super.handleMessage(msg);
            } catch (RuntimeException x) {
                // Pass the exception back to the calling thread (will be in args.result)
                WorkerArgs args = (WorkerArgs) msg.obj;
                Message reply = args.handler.obtainMessage(msg.what);
                args.result = x;
                reply.obj = args;
                reply.arg1 = msg.arg1;
                reply.sendToTarget();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Handler createHandler(Looper looper) {
        return new SturdyWorkerHandler(looper);
    }

    /**
     * Called when a runtime exception occurred during the asynchronous operation. 
     * <p>
     * The default re-throws the exception
     * @param token - The token that was passed into the operation
     * @param cookie - The cookie that was passed into the operation
     * @param error - The <code>RuntimeException</code> that was thrown during 
     * the operation
     */
    public void onError(int token, Object cookie, RuntimeException error) {
        throw error;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (msg.obj instanceof WorkerArgs) {
            WorkerArgs args = (WorkerArgs) msg.obj;
            if (args.result instanceof RuntimeException) {
                onError(msg.what, args.cookie, (RuntimeException) args.result);
                return;
            }
        }
        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice and elegant solution. I'm having the same issue of yours, even years after (few documentation about AsyncQueryHandler). Your solution is useful but how can I catch the RuntimeException thrown by AsyncQueryHandler? Suppose an error occurs, should I handle it inside the onError callback? Thank you

Comment: Yes, the class is meant to be subclassed with exception handling taking place in the (overridden) onError callback